# Dell Power Edge 2850 running slow on 1 drive?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dell-poweredge, raid1

Would a dell poweredge 2850 running in a Raid 1 (mirroring) config run in a reduced performance state if one of the drives break? We're waiting on a replacement drive and getting numerous errors. Does it maybe go into some sort of automatic safe mode reduced performance state? Its a 15K drive.

Thanks,

john

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't confirm this but I suspect that the RAID controller will disable any features that use the controller cache while there's a failed member of the array, which will probably reduce the performance slightly.

Comment: Thanks Joe, its a database intense system so it would be really good if someone could confirm this as it would dramatically reduce performance

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only going to be reading from one drive, it's potentially only half the read performance it'd have in full RAID1, so I'd expect it to be slower on reads.